# Select one form from many others on the page and save data wfrom input in it to databese

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I came across one interesting problem during website development. I have about thousand forms which are rendered by PHP:

```
 <form id="form'.$mailing_recipients[$i][recipient_id].'"><td>
                <input type="text" class="text_note" name="note_text" value="'.$mailing_recipients[$i][recipient_note].'">
                <button type="submit" class="btn_note save" id="'.$mailing_recipients[$i][recipient_id].'" value="'.$mailing_recipients[$i][recipient_id].'">Save</button></td>
        </form>
```

They look like this on frontend:

```
<form id="1"><td>
                <input type="text" class="text_note" name="note_text" value="'.$mailing_recipients[$i][recipient_note].'">
                <button type="submit" class="btn_note save" id="'.$mailing_recipients[$i][recipient_id].'" value="'.$mailing_recipients[$i][recipient_id].'">Save</button></td>
        </form>
```

To save test in any of them, I use JQuery:

```
jQuery("#form4").submit(function (event) {
             event.preventDefault();
             jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://www.someurl/admin-ajax.php",
                    data: {
                 action: "note_save",
                        id: event.target.id,
                        note_text: $(this).serialize()
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                 console.log("AJAX response : ", response);
             }
                });
            });
```

The problem is that jQuery does not pick form with id I want. So, I need any universal method for picking form which has text in it.

Comment: Are you duplicating `form4` as an ID?

Comment: try `jQuery("form#4").submit` as your selector instead

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the id of any form you can use a generic selector and get the id attribute of the form selected:

```
jQuery("form").submit(function (event) { // use 'form' in the selector
    var formID = $(this).attr('id'); // get the id of the form
```